# How do I create a link to google image search via HTML form?

Tags: html

Trying to make Google Image Search Clone using HTML form where after entering text in the search field it will take you directly to Google Image search results page.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
<body>
    <form action="https://google.com/search">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
    </form>
</body>
```

It will take to normal google search, how do I change it to google image search result page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to change the action, as such:

```html
<form method="get" action="http://images.google.com/images">
  <input type="text" name="q" />
  <input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I don't know how did I miss it. I was trying something like
`<form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&">
  <input type="text" name="q" />
  <input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
</form>`

How do I find url for say if I want to do it for I am feeling lucky search?

Comment: Since there is no "I am feeling lucky" option for searching images on Google, I assume you want it for text search. In that case, you have to change the action to: `<form method="get" action="http://images.google.com/search">` and either change the current input, or add a new one, like this: `<input type="submit" name="btn2" value="I am Feeling Lucky" class="button">`

Comment: Yes figured it out :) Thanks!

Comment: Your code works great. But how do you know it is the action? In the result page, the address still starts with `https://www.google.com/search`

Answer (score 7):

Google image search link is of the following format
[https://www.google.com/search?q=```query```&tbm=isch](https://www.google.com/search?q=%60%60%60query%60%60%60&tbm=isch)

Each of the parameters, q and tbm, requires an input tag but tbm does not require any user input.
'GET_parameter_name=value' for every input tag before submit button is appended by '&'.

```html
        
<form action="https://www.google.com/search">
  <input type="text" name="q" id="box">
  <input type="hidden" name="tbm" value="isch">
  <input type="submit" value="Image Search" >
</form>
```

Source:
https://stenevang.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/google-advanced-power-search-url-request-parameters/

https://www.xul.fr/javascript/parameters.php