# Stop function from functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm modifying a webpage, it has a button, it is coded so mouseup goes to a link, I want to change this, adding mouseup functions don't work; mousedown works but I have to hold the mousedown for a second or two otherwise the original function still occurs.

```
var duma = $('input')[0].value;
var siq = $('.inline-nav-menu__link')[1];
$(siq).mousedown(function(){
window.location = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+duma+'&sxsrf=APq-WBtOrInsFht_VAH6gWFlCceGK46ylQ:1649149133894&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdvbqix_z2AhWtxzgGHW7GCh0Q_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1366&bih=696&dpr=1';
})
```

This works but I have to keep the mouse held down for a lil bit
Changing that to mouseup doesn't work

---

---

I inspected the element further, it had an attribute named formAction which had the link to the respective page. Changing said attribute solved the first problem. But now the page is going to google web instead of images...

```
var duma = $('input')[0].value;
var siq = $('.inline-nav-menu__link')[1];
$(siq)[0].formAction='https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q='+duma+'';
```

Comment: Have You Tried Using `$(siq).mouseup(function(){})` to remove the mouse up function?

Comment: **mouseup goes to a link** just remove the mouseup event?

Comment: @Lain It looks like OP has an extension/userscript, and the event has been attached using an anonymous function. How to remove the event in that case, as `.off` works for events attached by `.on` only.

Comment: If that is the case: clone the button, append it below the original, remove the original, add event to the clone. I aint fluent in jQuery, so I am not going to post an actual answer.

Comment: FYI, this is for startpage.com The above code used in combination with github.com/fanfare/googleimagesrestored will work like a charm when it functions. Code inserted with User JavaScript and CSS, using the latest version of Vivaldi Browser. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld

Comment: I tried cloning, same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Needed to change form values.
Used the info on google search forms from link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65032682/10824788

```
var duma = $('input')[0].value;
var siq = $('.inline-nav-menu__link')[1];
var derka = 'https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&';
$(siq)[0].form[2].name="q";
$(siq)[0].form[2].value=duma;
$(siq)[0].form[4].name="tbm"
$(siq)[0].form[4].value="isch"
$(siq)[0].formAction=derka;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add an event listener, you're creating a function (that is a Javascript object) and binding it to a specific event.

To remove the listener, you have to pass to `.removeEventListener()` a reference to that same function.

Working with jQuery, there's also the `element.off('event_type')` method, but it works only on listeners previously attached with the jQuery `.on('event_type')` method.

If the listener refers to a **named** function you can do `element.removeEventListener('event', functionName)`.

If the listener is an anonymous function I'd do one of these:

**A)** **clone** the element with jQuery `clone()` method, so that the cloned element will not have any event listeners attached anymore. Then you could attach your own listeners.

**B)** if you don't need the original event listener, you can also **disable** it doing like this:

```
function stopEvent(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}

element.addEventListener('mouseup', stopEvent, true);
```

This way, using the `true` option in `.addEventListener`, you stop any event propagation at the beginning of the [capturing phase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events), so the event itself will never reach its target (for that `mouseup` event only).

The cons of the second option is that you cannot use that event anymore on that element, as it will never reach the target.
But, as you used a *named* function  to stop the propagation, you can now remove it with `element.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopEvent, true)` and bring back the original event listener to work again (because removing `stopEvent`, now the event propagates again to its target).