# How to get redirected to the google image search result of the page

Tags: html

```
<form action="https://images.google.co.in/searchbyimage">
      <input type="text" name="q" id="search_text_input">
      <input type="submit" value="Image Search" id="search_button">
</form>
```

I want to get the google image result page of the text input value.

Comment: Answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63040965/how-do-i-create-a-link-to-google-image-search-via-html-form) may help.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
      <input type="text" name="q" id="search_text_input">
      <input type="submit" value="Image Search" id="search_button">
      <input type="hidden" name="tbm" value="isch">
</form>
```